# Does AudioWorklet provide the lowest latency for playing sound Chrome on PC and Android?

Tags: javascript, audio, super, latency, audio-worklet

I tried audio html tag, tonejs, audio web api and I still have about 110 ms with both android and PC's browser (chrome).

I saw there is this JavaScript audio worlet ( super() ) but I can't figure out if it's possible to play samples in this process

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the AudioWorklet's latency will be < 3ms (128 samples / 48,000hz = 2.67ms) and can function as a player by sending your decoded PCM samples to the output buffers in `process()`.  AudioWorklets are not widely supported in browsers, so [`AudioBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBuffer) is a good cross-browser alternative and works very well.

This example loads a bunch of audio files and instantly switches playback between them: https://opus-bitrates.anthum.com

**audio-player-worklet.js**

```
class AudioPlayer extends AudioWorkletProcessor {
  decodedAudio  // Float32Array data to play (interleaved or separate)

  constructor() {
    super()

    // set audio to play when received from main/worker thread
    this.port.onmessage = ({ data: { decodedAudio } }) => {
      this.decodedAudio = decodedAudio
    }
  }

  process(inputs, outputs) {
    if (this.decodedPCMAudio) {
      // copy 128 samples from decodedAudio to outputs channels
    }

    // run process() again for next 128 samples
    return true
  }
}

registerProcessor('audio-player', AudioPlayer)
```